# Stop encoding all outputs when window being captured with gdigrab is closed (ffmpeg)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam

I'm trying to capture and encode two streams at the same time - webcam image and desktop capture (specific window) - using `ffmpeg` on Windows. I came up the following command to accomplish this:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i title="<window>" -f dshow -i video="<camera>" \
    -map 0:v -codec:v libx264 -crf 24 -preset ultrafast -shortest out1.mp4 \
    -map 1:v -codec:v libx264 -crf 24 -preset ultrafast -shortest out2.mp4
```

The trick is I want both recordings to start and stop at exactly the same time, so that for example if I set the same framerate for both outputs I get the same number of frames in both (assuming hardware can keep up). And the command above does that, but only if I exit manually (by pressing `Q`). If I close the window being recorded the associated encoding stops after the following message:

```
[gdigrab @ 0000022c31d4b700] Can't find window '<window>', aborting.
```

However, the webcam recording keeps going. My question then is - is it possible to make it automatically stop at the exact same time. I would think that is what the `-shortest` option would do, but it seems to have no effect here. I also thought about tying both outputs together with a common audio input, but that seems like a huge workaround. As a side question - is closing the window being recorded actually acceptable?

-Mateusz

Comment: ffmpeg is designed to handle multiple inputs and outputs in the same command, so -shortest applies only to the output to which it is applied. Are you encoding or streamcopying?

Comment: @Gyan encoding to H.264; I tried adding `-shortest` for the camera output only but sadly it doesn't work either.

Comment: Then share your actual commands.

Comment: @Gyan I've edited my post and added the full command including encoding options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method. The two output durations aren't guaranteed to be identical but they will be close.

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i title="<window>" -f dshow -i video="<camera>" \
       -map 0:v -map 1:v -flags +global_header -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -preset ultrafast \
       -shortest -f tee "[select=\'v:0\']out1.mp4|[select=\'v:1\']out2.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! As a follow up - would it be possible to set different CRF values for both outputs?

Comment: @MateuszDuchalski Try with stream specifiers: `-crf:v:0 24 -crf:v:1 30`